# create new object within C# Linq syntax on Select

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of `Vector2` objects. I want to select a value from each element and sort these values. After that, I want to get the lowest value.

```
Vector2 cheapestCellPosition = openCells.Select(x => new {
        Vector2 = x,
        Value = GetCostToTarget(x, targetPosition) + GetCell(x).Cost.GetValueOrDefault()
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Value)
    .First();
```

This code throws an error

> CS0029  C# Cannot implicitly convert anonymous type: Sym.Vector2
>   Vector2, int Value to Sym.Vector2

How can I fix this? I need to setup the Value property based on the current element.

Comment: Are you implementing A-Star?

Comment: yes, I want to create a A-Star algorithm

Comment: If you're interested in some thoughts on how you might implement this in C#, I wrote a series of articles about that in 2010. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/tag/astar/ -- **what you really need is a priority queue.**  Your approach works but you can get performance wins by using a properly implemented queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After this line:

`.Select(x => new { Vector2 = x, Value = GetCostToTarget(x, targetPosition) + GetCell(x).Cost.GetValueOrDefault() })`

You have a collection of anonymous objects with `Vector2` and `Value` properties. This is *not* a `Vector2`.

At the end when you use `First` you are still selecting the *first* of those anonymous objects. It's not a `Vector2`, so you can't assign it to a variable of type `Vector2`.

But if you just change it to:

`.First().Vector2`

That will get the `Vector2` property of the first anonymous object you selected. This *is* a `Vector2`, so it should be assignable to `cheapestCellPosition`

Although it's not the easiest thing to read, but your error is telling you this:

> CS0029 C# Cannot implicitly convert anonymous type: Sym.Vector2 Vector2, int Value to Sym.Vector2

It's telling you it can't convert the anonymous type with a `Vector2` property of type `Sym.Vector2` and a `Value` property of type `int` to type `Sym.Vector2`

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE: You are using this to implement the A-star algorithm.  Though the approach you are using works, you will probably be better off if you implement a priority queue; you can get significant performance wins by doing so.

---

It's unclear why you are going to the trouble of creating a sequence of anonymous types in the first place; why not simply write:

```
Vector2 cheapestCellPosition = openCells
  .OrderBy(x => GetCostToTarget(x, targetPosition) + GetCell(x).Cost.GetValueOrDefault())
  .First();
```

?

Note that though this is more efficient than what you wrote, is *not as  efficient as it could be*.

What you really want is the smallest item in a set. Unfortunately, that is not an operation that is provided in the standard sequence library.

Let's fix that.

What we want to write is:

```
Vector2 cheapestCellPosition = openCells
  .MinBy(x => GetCostToTarget(x, targetPosition) + GetCell(x).Cost.GetValueOrDefault());
```

Let's suppose the cost is a double, to make it easier.

```
static class Extensions 
{
  public static T MinBy(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, double> cost) 
  {
    T minItem = default(T);
    double? minCost = null;
    foreach(T item in items) 
    {
      double current = cost(item);
      if (minCost == null || current < minCost)
      {
        minCost = current;
        minItem = item;
      }
    }
    if (minCost == null) throw InvalidOperationException();
    return minItem;
  }
}
```

And we're done. We don't have to sort a list to find the smallest item!

**Exercise**: Suppose the cost function does not return a double. Can you genericize `MinBy` further, so that it can take any cost function?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're selecting the anonymous type which has both a `Vector2` property and a `Value` property, but then you're trying to assign the first one to a `Vector2` type.

If `openCells` is indeed an `IEnumerable<Vector2>`, then you can just remove the `Select` and put your ordering code directly in the `OrderBy` clause, and then return the `First` one:

```
Vector2 cheapestCellPosition = openCells
    .OrderBy(cell => GetCostToTarget(cell, targetPosition) + 
                     GetCell(cell).Cost.GetValueOrDefault())
    .First();
```